# R summarize dataframe with unique features

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I have a large table in the following format:

```
Data <- data.frame("Chrom" = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr4", "chr4", "chr6"), "Site" = c(100, 200, 400, 140, 300, 400), "Heart" = c(20, 100, 0, 35, 92, 100), "Brain" = c(30, 40, 55, 100, 0, 100), "Liver" = c(100, 55, 20, 90, 0, 0), "Lungs" = c(100, 0, 80, 40, 30, 0))
```

Giving:

```
> Data
  Chrom Site Heart Brain Liver Lungs
1  chr1  100    20    30   100   100
2  chr1  200   100    40    55     0
3  chr1  400     0    55    20    80
4  chr4  140    35   100    90    40
5  chr4  300    92     0     0    30
6  chr6  400   100   100     0     0
```

I want to make a figure similar to this published figure.  (http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2015/150218/ncomms7363/fig_tab/ncomms7363_F1.html):

[image]

Basically for each row (based on common Chrom and Site), I want to see how many intermediate values there are. I define intermediate here as values between 15 and 85. Then for each organ I would like to know how many rows are intermediate in all organs, that organ only, shared with two organs or three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing the power of data.table:

**Setup**

```
library(data.table)

Data <- data.frame("Chrom" = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr4", "chr4", "chr6"), "Site" = c(100, 200, 400, 140, 300, 400), "Heart" = c(20, 100, 0, 35, 92, 100), "Brain" = c(30, 40, 55, 100, 0, 100), "Liver" = c(100, 55, 20, 90, 0, 0), "Lungs" = c(100, 0, 80, 40, 30, 0))

DT <- data.table(Data)

isintermediate <- function(x){
  return(x >=15 & x <= 85)
}


DI <- DT[ , list(Chrom, Site,
                 Heart = isintermediate(Heart),
                 Brain = isintermediate(Brain),
                 Liver = isintermediate(Liver),
                 Lungs = isintermediate(Lungs))]
```

This creates a matrix `DI` that looks like:

```
> DI
   Chrom Site Heart Brain Liver Lungs
1:  chr1  100  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2:  chr1  200 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
3:  chr1  400 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
4:  chr4  140  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
5:  chr4  300 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
6:  chr6  400 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

With a `TRUE` or `FALSE` if a value is intermediate or not. (Might be a quicker way to do this than creating the function, but I find this way easy to follow).

**Count Intermediate**

Now, counting the Intermediate values by Chrom + Site is simple

```
# NoI is Number Intermediate

> DI[, list(NoI = Heart + Brain + Liver + Lungs), by = c("Chrom","Site")]
   Chrom Site NoI
1:  chr1  100   2
2:  chr1  200   2
3:  chr1  400   3
4:  chr4  140   2
5:  chr4  300   1
6:  chr6  400   0
```

**Intermediate Count by Organ**

For the number of intermediate across, this gets more complicated. First, melt the data using reshape

```
library(reshape2)

DA <- melt(DI, id.vars = c("Chrom","Site"))[value == TRUE]
```

this gives:

```
> DA
    Chrom Site variable value
 1:  chr1  100    Heart  TRUE
 2:  chr4  140    Heart  TRUE
 3:  chr1  100    Brain  TRUE
 4:  chr1  200    Brain  TRUE
 5:  chr1  400    Brain  TRUE
 6:  chr1  200    Liver  TRUE
 7:  chr1  400    Liver  TRUE
 8:  chr1  400    Lungs  TRUE
 9:  chr4  140    Lungs  TRUE
10:  chr4  300    Lungs  TRUE
```

We are only interested in the TRUE values, hence the `[value == TRUE]` line

Now we need a count of intermediate values for each site, but appended for each organ. We can use `.N` and `by=` to do this, and then merge back to our initial table:

`DA <- merge(DA,DA[, list(IAcc = .N), by = c("Chrom","Site")], by = c("Chrom","Site"))`

Giving:

```
> DA
    Chrom Site variable value IAcc
 1:  chr1  100    Heart  TRUE    2
 2:  chr1  100    Brain  TRUE    2
 3:  chr1  200    Brain  TRUE    2
 4:  chr1  200    Liver  TRUE    2
 5:  chr1  400    Brain  TRUE    3
 6:  chr1  400    Liver  TRUE    3
 7:  chr1  400    Lungs  TRUE    3
 8:  chr4  140    Heart  TRUE    2
 9:  chr4  140    Lungs  TRUE    2
10:  chr4  300    Lungs  TRUE    1
```

Now all that is left is to get a count of unique IAccs by each organ, which we can get with the `table` function:

```
Output <- data.table(table(DA[,list(variable,IAcc)]))
> Output
    variable IAcc N
 1:    Heart    1 0
 2:    Brain    1 0
 3:    Liver    1 0
 4:    Lungs    1 1
 5:    Heart    2 2
 6:    Brain    2 2
 7:    Liver    2 1
 8:    Lungs    2 1
 9:    Heart    3 0
10:    Brain    3 1
11:    Liver    3 1
12:    Lungs    3 1
```

Where `IAcc` is the number of organs (including itself) that also have an intermediate value at the same Chrom and Site, and N is the number of times that is seen.

Finally, to plot (forgive the default colours):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Output, aes(x = variable, y = N, fill = IAcc)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice thorough answer! For your repeated application of `isintermediate`, one standard syntax would be to use something like `DT[,c(list(Chron),lapply(.SD,isintermediate)),.SDcols=yourcols]`. Similarly `NoI` could be `Reduce("+",.SD)`, using the same `yourcols` string of column names. Also, fyi, melt will soon be included with data.table, and can be found in the development version on github (I think...I don't use it).

Comment: @Frank  `Reduce` looks like the right way to do it... And agreed on the `.SD`, might even be simpler with: `DI <- DT[ , lapply(.SD,isintermediate),by = c("Chrom","Site")]` as SDcols can be implicit

Comment: Very nice answer! Also like your first line ;-).

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question (for each row find how many intermediate values there are), you could try something like:

```
is_intermediate = function(x) {
    return(x < 85 & x > 15)
}
res = sapply(Data[, 2:length(Data)], is_intermediate)
rowSums(res)
```

If you're comfortable with dplyr + tidyr, you can do something like:

```
Data %>% gather(organ, value, Heart:lungs) %>%
    group_by(Chrom, Site) %>%
    summarise(n_intermediate = sum(is_intermediate(value)))
```

Which would give you number of intermediate values for each Chrom / Site combination.

For the next part you can do something like:

```
Data %>% select(-Chrom, -Site) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(is_intermediate)) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

This would get you the number of intermediate values by column.

Comment: This is pretty helpful except I'm still not sure how to summarize the number of common vs. unique intermediate sites per tissue